# Regular field validator on drop down lists

Tags: validation

I have a form in ASP.NET and this form has four drop down lists.  I want to make it so that a user cannot choose from the second, until the first has a value in it.  the third can't have a value until the second, the fourth can't until the third.

Does anyone have tips?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Ajax Control Toolkit  :

Check the sample on

[ASP.NET Ajax CascadingDropDown Demonstration](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/CascadingDropDown/CascadingDropDown.aspx)

Regards